# PHP Curl GET request not working but works fine in POSTMAN

Tags: php, php-curl

I am trying to get product data from google merchant center (google shopping ), my curl command works fine on postman, but not on php. Please help me

On postman:
[image]

On Php:

```php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://shoppingcontent.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/436306321/products',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0ARrdaM8TK4rZeVRnsj9MgcFg3STE1EqGvwj20J-REq8f6poCzGIv2MzUIegdSP1DDa_-HQpHIQNBTU6Rnxf7HsnWCjwkP7_pwkp-kr5zm0o0Z6EuZCVa4IdwHzX7MGM8SQ-94Vkxps4JRSbkgplYo4w1K8lPwQ'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Seems to return a bad token response... how did you copy the code from postman and have you checked your token?